# Extracting tar files on Mac os

Tags: macos

I need to extract some tarballs which are packed as xz, gz and lz formats.
I`m using Mac, and my question is that how can I extract these?

I thought about http://unarchiver.c3.cx/unarchiver but have no idea how to use it.

Thanks.

Comment: `The Unarchiver` you mention is great. Just right-click on a file and let it get on with it.

Comment: alternatively, you can just drag your tar-files onto the Unarchiver-icon to unpack the files with it.

Comment: Ok thanks. I downloaded the Unarchiver 3.9.1.zip so that`s probably the righ file. I will give it a try.